# background image fallback: should I use CSV or multiple rules?

Tags: css, background-image, gradient, fallback

Most modern browsers, even IE9, support comma-separated values (CSV) of `background-image`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image), the painting order is right-to-left—the first image defined will be stacked on top and any subsequent images will be stacked underneath (thus hidden if the first image is opaque).

```
.masthead {
  background-image: url('top.jpg'), url('bottom.jpg');
}
```

[Harry Roberts uses an insightful technique](http://csswizardry.com/2016/10/improving-perceived-performance-with-multiple-background-images/) by setting a gradient as a fallback for while the background image is still loading or fails to load. He recommends using the CSV feature.

```
.masthead {
  background-image: url('top.jpg'),
    linear-gradient(to right, #807363 0%, #251d16 50%, #3f302b 75%, #100b09 100%);
}
```

Is this method more performant than simply defining the `background-image` property twice? What advantages or disadvantages does this technique have over the following?

```
.masthead {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #807363 0%, #251d16 50%, #3f302b 75%, #100b09 100%);
  background-image: url('top.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first two examples use [CSS3 multiple backgrounds](http://font-size:%2028px;). You should not use this as a background fallback technique for various reasons, such as performance and browser support.

The last example should be used for background fallback. From memory, the last background-image definition will be used by default, and if the value cannot be parsed, the previous definition will be used, etc.

Also see the [background generator by ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) which automatically generates the required fallback.